# Copy documentFile to external Storage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy the documentFile to the external storage.

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,desFile);
```

I tried this but i think it's for file only.

Comment: Get the `Uri` from the `DocumentFile`. Pass that to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. That gives you an `InputStream` for the content. From there, you would copy the data to a `FileOutputStream` pointing to your desired file (e.g., from `getExternalFilesDir()`).

Comment: but what's the output path. is there anyway to save it to android/media/mypackagename and also make it accessable by other apps, the reason i wanna do that is to access it whitout any permission.

Comment: "is there anyway to save it to android/media/mypackagename" -- probably that is `getExternalMediaDir()` on `Context`, though I am not completely certain. "and also make it accessable by other apps" -- the location that you requested will not be accessible to other apps on Android 11 and higher.

Comment: What about `getExternalFileDir(Envirement.MEDIA_SHARED)` is it accessable by other app, or i should use `MediaStore`.

Comment: "is it accessable by other app" -- not on Android 11 and higher. If this is actual media, using `MediaStore` or writing to a standard media directory is your best bet. While `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is marked as deprecated, [it will be restored to normal with Android 12L](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html).

Comment: thanks for ur time, do you know how i can use MediaStore and documentFile